# i'm trying to change the data type of day() function to integer but it won't work

Tags: python, function, recursion, types, integer

im trying change the data type of my function from float to integer but i tried print(int(day(hour) but it won't work. and also im trying to get rid of the "print" in my recursive function

```
minute_input = int(input("minutes: "))

minute = minute_input % 60
hour = minute_input / 60

def day(hour):
  print(hour) #and also i'm trying to get rid of this but if i don't write it, the code won't work at all
  if hour < 24:
    return 
  if hour > 24:
    return (day(hour / 24))

print(int(day(hour)))
```

Comment: `return` is equivalent to `return None`. Did you want `return hour` instead? (Also, what if `hour == 24`)?

Comment: Recursion, by the way, is a terrible way to implement the function. You probably just want `return hour // 24`.

Comment: (Same for `hour`; use `minute_input // 60`. You can also simply write `hour, minute = divmod(minute_input, 60)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must avoid using recursion when the problem can be solved with simple operators as follows:

```
minute_input = int(input("minutes: "))

minute = minute_input % 60
hour = minute_input / 60

def day(hour):
  return hour / 24

print(day(hour), hour)
```

**Output:**

```
minutes: 60
0.041666666666666664 1.0
```

Also, if you want to get the days value as an integer, you can change the last print instruction to:

```
print(int(day(hour)), hour)
```